# NDSolve complains about missing derivatives of dependent variables in Mathematica 9

Tags: differential-equations, version-9

In *Mathematica* 8

```
NDSolve[{x[t] == 1, x[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

solves fine and returns

```
{{x[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t]}}
```

while *Mathematica* 9 raises

> NDSolve::derivs: No derivatives of dependent variables were found in the equations. NDSolve is designed to solve differential or differential algebraic equations. Use NSolve or FindRoot to numerically solve algebraic equations. >>

I get the point, but is there maybe a way to restore the old behavior via `NDSolve`'s options system?

Comment: Why would you want to restore the old behaviour?

Comment: These type of equations systems come from model descriptions (not my own; why would anyone describe such a pointless system, right?) and I would like to be able to reliable solve them (without manual intervention). Anyways, I hacked my way around it (see my answer, which I will not accept ...).

Comment: The old behavior allowed to solve equations of the form `f[x,y[x]]==0`, which cannot be solved by any other built-in methods.

Answer (score 2):

Based on an idea from my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166921/add-interpolating-functions-over-an-unstructured-mesh-to-get-a-single-interpolat/166970#166970):

Add a dummy derivative in a separate equation to trick Mathematica into not complaining:

```
NDSolve[{dummy'[t] == 0, x[t] == 1, x[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
(* {{x[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][t]}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a real answer to my own question because I am not restoring NDSolve's old behavior. I am posting it in the (unlikely) case anyone has the same problem and is looking for a solution. The following function

```
catchMissingDeriv=Quiet[
    Check[
        ReleaseHold[#],
        NSolve[DeleteCases[#[[1,1]],_[0]==_],#[[1,2]]],
    {NDSolve::derivs}],
{NDSolve::derivs}]&;
```

catches `NDSolve::derivs` and switches to `NSolve` to calculate a solution. So,

```
catchMissingDeriv[Hold[NDSolve[{x[t] == 1, x[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]]]
```

will return

```
{{x[t] -> 1.}}
```