# Add interpolating functions over an unstructured mesh to get a single interpolating function

Tags: performance-tuning, interpolation, mesh, finite-element-method

In a Newton iterative FEM PDE solver I am writing, each iterative step involves updating the current solution function `u` by adding to it the increment function `du`, which is the solution of some linearised PDE whose coefficients depend on the current `u`. Both `u` and `du` are `InterpolatingFunction`.

Now, as the number of iterates `n` grows, it becomes quite inefficient to evaluate the sum of `n` interpolating functions.

**How can two `InterpolatingFunction` over a finite element mesh be added together to get a single `InterpolatingFunction`, whilst keeping all the original unstructured mesh properties / interpolation order?**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
<< NDSolve`FEM`
rad = 5; th = Pi/4;
reg = Disk[{0,0}, rad, {-th,th}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg];
```

Say the two functions to be added are

```
f1 = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}] == 1^2 * u[x,y]
       + NeumannValue[1, True]}, u, Element[{x,y}, mesh]];
f2 = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}] == 2^2 * u[x,y]
       + NeumannValue[1, True]}, u, Element[{x,y}, mesh]];
```

**Attempt 0.**

```
sum0 = Function[{x,y}, f1[x,y] + f2[x,y] // Evaluate];
Do[  f1[0,0], 100000] // AbsoluteTiming  (* {0.58909, Null} *)
Do[sum0[0,0], 100000] // AbsoluteTiming  (* {1.64215, Null} *)
```

Using `Function` obviously doesn't lump the sum into a single `InterpolatingFunction`.

**Attempt 1.**

```
sum1 = NDSolveValue[s[x,y] == f1[x,y] + f2[x,y], s, Element[{x,y}, mesh]];
```

> NDSolveValue::derivs: No derivatives of dependent variables were found in the equations. NDSolveValue is designed to solve differential or differential algebraic equations. Use NSolve or FindRoot to numerically solve algebraic equations.

See [(23416)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23416/ndsolve-complains-about-missing-derivatives-of-dependent-variables-in-mathematic); it's a pity you can't solve "zeroth order differential equations" anymore.

**Attempt 2.**

```
sum2 = FunctionInterpolation[f1[x,y] + f2[x,y], Element[{x,y}, mesh]];
```

> FunctionInterpolation::range: "Argument {x,y}[Element]mesh is not in the form of a range specification, {x, xmin, xmax}."

Using the form `{x, xmin, xmax}, ...` is not an option because the `reg` is not rectangular and `mesh` is unstructured, and I want the sum to inherit these properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this (assuming of course that the `InterpolatingFunction` `f1` and `f2` are generating using the same mesh):

```
f12 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, f1["ValuesOnGrid"] + f2["ValuesOnGrid"]]
```

Where `ElementMeshInterpolation` is from the

```
NDSolve`FEM`
```

package.

```
f1[1, 1] + f2[1, 1]
(* -1.84159 *)

f12[1, 1]
(* -1.84159 *)

Do[f1[0, 0], 100000] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.223145, Null} *)

Do[f12[0, 0], 100000] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.213769, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Attempt 3.**

It turns out you can trick Mathematica into not complaining about lack of derivatives by adding a dependent derivative in a separate equation:

```
sum3 = NDSolveValue[
         {Laplacian[dummy[x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
          s[x, y] == f1[x, y] + f2[x, y]
         }, s, Element[{x, y}, mesh]]
```

Of course this is slower than chuy's method.